# Remove rows with the same value across all columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame (df) that looks like below:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

cars <- c("Car1", "Car2", "Car3", "Car4", "Car5", "Car6", "Car7", "Car8", "Car9")
test1 <- c(0,0,3,1,4,2,1,3,0)
test2 <- c(0,0,2,1,0,2,2,5,0)
test3 <- c(1,0,5,1,2,2,6,7,0)
test4 <- c(2,NA,2,1,2,2,1,1,0)
test5 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,2,1,3,0)
test6 <- c(1,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,0)
test7 <- c(3,0,2,1,0,2,1,1,0)

df <- data.frame(cars,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7)

#df
   cars test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
#1 Car1     0     0     1     2     0     1     3
#2 Car2     0     0     0    NA     0     0     0
#3 Car3     3     2     5     2     1     1     2
#4 Car4     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#5 Car5     4     0     2     2     0     1     0
#6 Car6     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#7 Car7     1     2     6     1     1     3     1
#8 Car8     3     5     7     1     3     4     1
#9 Car9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I want to **remove any rows that have the same value throughout the entire row** (in the example above, I would like to keep rows 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 and remove the rest).

I've figured out how to remove all rows that have zeros

```
 df$sum <- rowSums(df[,c(2:8)], na.rm = T )
 df.all0 <- df[which(df$sum == 0),]
```

However, this doesn't necessarily work for all the other rows.  Unlike other questions, this question asks to look for duplicates across the entire row, not just specific columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @akaDrHouse  I do not see how my question is a duplicate.  I'm asking about the entire row, not some duplicates in columns.

Comment: you are correct; I missunderstood. Sorry about that.

Comment: is there anything like this for pandas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
keep <- apply(df[2:8], 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) != 1)
df[keep, ]

  cars test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
1 Car1     0     0     1     2     0     1     3
3 Car3     3     2     5     2     1     1     2
5 Car5     4     0     2     2     0     1     0
7 Car7     1     2     6     1     1     3     1
8 Car8     3     5     7     1     3     4     1
```

Comment: Hi @JasonWang!  What would be the best way save the car ID of the rows that were removed?

Comment: `which(!keep)` will give you the row index you removed.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option with `rowSums`; the logic is to check if there is any value in the row that is different (NA doesn't count) from one of the columns that you are interested in:

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] != df[[2]], na.rm = TRUE) != 0,]

#  cars test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
#1 Car1     0     0     1     2     0     1     3
#3 Car3     3     2     5     2     1     1     2
#5 Car5     4     0     2     2     0     1     0
#7 Car7     1     2     6     1     1     3     1
#8 Car8     3     5     7     1     3     4     1
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your thoughts.  I'm a little confused by your logic. Are you saying you are comparing all columns against the test1 column?

Comment: Oh wait! I think I understand.  You are using test1 as a reference point to check if all other columns have the same value (or not).  Right?

Comment: Yes check all *test* columns against *test1*, if there is one column has a non NA value that is different, the rowSums will be different from zero, and thus you will keep it.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `Map` with `Reduce`

```
df[c(Reduce(`+`, Map(function(x,y) x != y & !is.na(x), df[-1], list(df[2]))) != 0),]
#  cars test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
#1 Car1     0     0     1     2     0     1     3
#3 Car3     3     2     5     2     1     1     2
#5 Car5     4     0     2     2     0     1     0
#7 Car7     1     2     6     1     1     3     1
#8 Car8     3     5     7     1     3     4     1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    filter_at(vars(starts_with("test")), any_vars((. != test1)))
#   cars test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
#1 Car1     0     0     1     2     0     1     3
#2 Car3     3     2     5     2     1     1     2
#3 Car5     4     0     2     2     0     1     0
#4 Car7     1     2     6     1     1     3     1
#5 Car8     3     5     7     1     3     4     1
```