# Delete a row where all specified fields contain the same string value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains a variety of values similar to the example below.  I don't even know how to create sample data (sorry guys, I've been trying) so I'm typing the example in plain text.

Anyway, what I want to do is find all rows containing the string "NoRep" in every field except the "Name" column, and then delete those rows from the dataframe.

I've searched this forum and found examples that will do this for numeric values, but I can't find one that operates on strings.  This link  is an example of one which does NOT work on string values  [Remove rows with the same value across all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398252/remove-rows-with-the-same-value-across-all-columns)

Column names:

Name, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4

Data:

```
Joe, Phone, Text, NoRep, Phone

Bob, Phone, Phone, NoRep, Text

John, NoRep, NoRep, NoRep, NoRep

Bill, Phone, Text, Phone, Phone
```

Successful code will take the dataframe that looks like the above (like I said, I can't seem to even make a dataframe out of it) and then delete the "John" row on the basis of the fact that Fields 1-4 all contain the text "NoRep."

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Field")), all_vars(. == "NoRep"))`

Comment: That prints out a list of the field names followed by a bunch of  lines with the "Name" field and then a bunch of "NoRep" repetitions till it hits max_print, but does not appear to do anything to the rows in question.

Comment: I think it should be the reverse `df1 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Field")), any_vars(. != "NoRep"))`

Comment: That returned me a dataframe with 68 variables and 0 rows.  The specific version on my actual data was: df2 <- df1 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Field")), any_vars(. != "NoRep"))

Comment: I can't reproduce it as I get the 3 rows excepthe one with `John`

Comment: `df1 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Field")), any_vars(. != "NoRep"))#
  Name Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
1  Joe  Phone   Text  NoRep  Phone
2  Bob  Phone  Phone  NoRep   Text
3 Bill  Phone   Text  Phone  Phone`

Comment: Check if there are leadinglagging spaces etc. in each column as we are doing a fixed match with `==`

Comment: Don't know what I did wrong last time, but this worked.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't mark it as "solved" though because the forum still thinks it's a dup.